# VMware ESXi 4.1 failing to delete files from datastore browser (vSphere Client)

Tags: esxi

Receiving Error stating "Error caused by file /vmfs/volumes/[ID]/Delete/Delete1

(Names a result of attempting to rename from some advice on VMware forums.)

Any input is appreciated.

P.S - I have restarted the host services.

P.P.S - Am I on the right path?

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008728

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are seen when the resource is busy and used by some other application.  You need to make sure that it is not used by any application.  Bring down all virtual machines, reboot ESXi and goto CLI mode.  Goto the directory that contains the file you wish to work on, and from there you should be able to delete the file.